# What is the purpose of the -self method in NSObject-conformant classes?

Tags: objective-c, nsobject, foundation

That's it. Why would anyone want (at least as a public API) a method such as that? Is there any practical use for it?

Comment: The question was "Why would anyone want..." or "What is the purpose...", not "Why is it there?"

Comment: This seems like a valid question. Why the downvotes?

Comment: It's very open ended...there's no real straight answer. Like @H2CO3 asked, why would anyone _not_ want it?

Comment: There is no real reason. It's there, perhaps it could be used. But there is no reason to not use it.

Comment: @H2CO3 and @John - Have you ever had a practical reason to use the `self` method? I'm curious too when this would be useful. Why would I ever need to call `[self self]` or `[someObject self]`? Before this question, I hadn't even noticed that method existed.

Comment: I use it in cycript purely through laziness.  view = [array[1] view]; then I drop the index to index 2 and it IS a view, so doesn't have a view method. Rather then have to go back and delete lines I tend to rewrite it to [array[2] self], especially when I'll have to change again for the 3'rd index.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `self` method is useful for Key-Value Coding (KVC).

With KVC, you can treat an object somewhat like a dictionary. You can access a property of the object using a string containing the name of the property, like this: `[view valueForKey:@"superview"]`.  You walk down a chain of properties using a string containing a key path, like this: `[view valueForKeyPath:@"superview.superview.center"]`.

Since `NSObject` has a `self` method, you can use `self` as the key or key path: `[view valueForKey:@"self"]`.  So if you're constructing your key paths programmatically, or reading them from a file, using `"self"` as a key may allow you to avoid writing a special case.

You can also use `self` in predicates, like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self beginswith \"foo\""];
NSArray *filteredArray = [arrayOfStrings filteredArrayWithPredicate:predicate];
```

I don't know whether `NSPredicate` actually uses the `self` method (perhaps via KVC) in this case.  It's certainly possible.

Comment: "SELF" is documented as a special constant in NSPredicates, like "nil", "NULL" and a bunch of others.  It could be mapped to the actual "self" method, but to me the documentation implies it's special.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why "self" was added originally, but one thing it did come in handy for was protecting interior pointers to objects.  Apple's official recommendation was to insert a [foo self] call after you're done with the interior pointer; the method call does nothing functionally but ensures the compiler keeps foo around until then.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's to do with the ObjC runtime.

```
objc_msgSend(autoreleasePool, sel_registerName("drain"));
BOOL AppDel_didFinishLaunching(struct AppDel *self, SEL _cmd, void *application, void *options)
```

The first argument is self. I think it has something to do with that. In all honesty though as it would end up as:

```
id self(struct id *self, SEL _cmd) {
    return self;
}
```

....It made more sense before I started writing this response.